# Issue with uninstalling spring-security-ldap plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I have a frustrating situation I cannot understand. I am developing an application using the Grails framework (Version: 3.4.0.RELEASE). I used the spring-security-core(1.2.7.3) and spring-security-ldap(1.0.6) plugins to manage credentials. I uninstall the ldap plugin, and for some reason it causes errors. Now when I try to run the project it gives me java errors for one of my groovy classes, such as "...java:15: ')' expected..." or "...java:15: ';' expected...". Everything ran great until I uninstall the ldap plugin. During compile it says "Compile error during compilation with javac". What's happening here? Let me know if I need to show some other code. And this is during runtime. There are no errors showing. I'm in such a hurry to finish the project that each time I get this problem I just create a new project and it runs fine. Just trying to avoid that as I progress in the project

EDIT:

Console output

```
| Loading Grails 2.2.4
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application....
| Compiling 21 source files.
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
Compile error during compilation with javac.
C:\Users\cpu user\AppData\Local\Temp\groovy-generated-75457048637925996-java-source\com\example\ldap\MyUserDetails.java:15: ')' expected
super ((java.lang.String)null, (java.lang.String)null, false, false, false, false, (java.util.Collection<java.lang.Object extends org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority>)null);
                                                                                                                         ^
C:\Users\cpu user\AppData\Local\Temp\groovy-generated-75457048637925996-java-source\com\example\ldap\MyUserDetails.java:15: ';' expected
super ((java.lang.String)null, (java.lang.String)null, false, false, false, false, (java.util.Collection<java.lang.Object extends org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority>)null);
                                                                                                                                 ^
C:\Users\cpu user\AppData\Local\Temp\groovy-generated-75457048637925996-java-source\com\example\ldap\MyUserDetails.java:15: illegal start of expression
super ((java.lang.String)null, (java.lang.String)null, false, false, false, false, (java.util.Collection<java.lang.Object extends org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority>)null);
                                                                                                                                     ^
C:\Users\cpu user\AppData\Local\Temp\groovy-generated-75457048637925996-java-source\com\example\ldap\MyUserDetails.java:15: ';' expected
super ((java.lang.String)null, (java.lang.String)null, false, false, false, false, (java.util.Collection<java.lang.Object extends org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority>)null);
                                                                                                                                                     ^
C:\Users\cpu user\AppData\Local\Temp\groovy-generated-75457048637925996-java-source\com\example\ldap\MyUserDetails.java:15: illegal start of expression
super ((java.lang.String)null, (java.lang.String)null, false, false, false, false, (java.util.Collection<java.lang.Object extends org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority>)null);
                                                                                                                                                                                     ^
C:\Users\cpu user\AppData\Local\Temp\groovy-generated-75457048637925996-java-source\com\example\ldap\MyUserDetails.java:15: not a statement
super ((java.lang.String)null, (java.lang.String)null, false, false, false, false, (java.util.Collection<java.lang.Object extends org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority>)null);
                                                                                                                                                                                    ^
C:\Users\cpu user\AppData\Local\Temp\groovy-generated-75457048637925996-java-source\com\example\ldap\MyUserDetails.java:15: not a statement
super ((java.lang.String)null, (java.lang.String)null, false, false, false, false, (java.util.Collection<java.lang.Object extends org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority>)null);
                                                                                                                                                                                      ^
C:\Users\cpu user\AppData\Local\Temp\groovy-generated-75457048637925996-java-source\com\example\ldap\MyUserDetails.java:15: ';' expected
super ((java.lang.String)null, (java.lang.String)null, false, false, false, false, (java.util.Collection<java.lang.Object extends org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority>)null);
                                                                                                                                                                                          ^
C:\Users\cpu user\AppData\Local\Temp\groovy-generated-75457048637925996-java-source\com\example\ldap\MyUserDetails.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class util
location: package java
super ((java.lang.String)null, (java.lang.String)null, false, false, false, false, (java.util.Collection<java.lang.Object extends org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority>)null);
                                                                                        ^
C:\Users\cpu user\AppData\Local\Temp\groovy-generated-75457048637925996-java-source\com\example\ldap\MyUserDetails.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class lang
location: package java
super ((java.lang.String)null, (java.lang.String)null, false, false, false, false, (java.util.Collection<java.lang.Object extends org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority>)null);
                                                                                                             ^
C:\Users\cpu user\AppData\Local\Temp\groovy-generated-75457048637925996-java-source\com\example\ldap\MyUserDetails.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor User(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean)
location: class org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
super ((java.lang.String)null, (java.lang.String)null, false, false, false, false, (java.util.Collection<java.lang.Object extends org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority>)null);
^
C:\Users\cpu user\AppData\Local\Temp\groovy-generated-75457048637925996-java-source\com\example\ldap\MyUserDetails.java:15: package security does not exist
super ((java.lang.String)null, (java.lang.String)null, false, false, false, false, (java.util.Collection<java.lang.Object extends org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority>)null);
                                                                                                                                                              ^
Note: C:\projects\new portal project\InfinityPortalIntranet\src\java\com\example\ldap\AuthenticateUser.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
12 errors`
```

---

EDIT 2:
MyUserDetails.Groovy

```
package com.example.ldap

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User

class MyUserDetails extends User {
    // extra instance variables
    final String fullname
    final String email
    final String title
    final String firstName
    final String lastName
    MyUserDetails(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired, 
        boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, 
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities, 
        String fullname, String email, String title, String firstName, String lastName) {

        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, 
            authorities)

        this.fullname = fullname 
        this.email = email 
        this.title = title 
        this.firstName = firstName
        this.lastName = lastName
        }
}
```

Comment: Going to need much better errors than what you have given. What are the exact compiler errors? What grails commands are you using?

Comment: @rmlan I'm exactly using grails commands. I'm using the GGTS editor. To uninstall the plugin I just right-clicked on the plugin, clicked uninstall. The console output said it was uninstalled, but I got a compile error that popped up. Sorry, but I can't remember exactly what it said then. To run I just used run-app. I'll add the console output

Comment: @rmlan I meant "I'm actually not using grails commands" not "I'm exactly using grails commands"

Comment: Alright, let's see the code for MyUserDetails.java

Comment: @rmlan That's the thing: it's actually MyUserDetails.groovy. Hold on